# How do you add new image sizes with a custom suffix in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, image-processing

How do you add new image sizes with a custom suffix in WordPress?

I'm looking to create 3 additional images sizes all with custom suffixes.

I know I can add new sizes by calling the following, but I don't know how to assign this sizes custom suffixes.

Here are the image sizes and suffix names I'm aiming for.

```
add_image_size( 'name-small', 300, 300, false );
add_image_size( 'name-medium', 600, 600, false );
add_image_size( 'name-large', 1024, 1024, false );
```